# Taking picture on Camera and preview image (result ) in an ImageView using Uri

Tags: java, android

I want to take picture with camera and preview that picture(result) on an image view but when i take picture it gives me error.

```
public class ActivityCamera extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE=1;
private ImageView mImageview;
private Button takepic ;
private static final  int GALLERY_REQUEST = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
    takepic= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
    takepic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent,CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        Uri imageuri = data.getData();
        mImageview.setImageURI(imageuri);

    }
}}
```

It does not show image on imagview.

Comment: "but when i take picture it gives me error." and the error is? Also on what version of android is the error happening

Comment: `and preview that picture`. Preview is before picture taken. The camera app lets you preview the scene. You only want to display the picture taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your onActivityResult code to following

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

Comment: may be because of your imageview size in xml

Comment: the imageview size is match-parent sir

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the below code for taking camera image and setting preview.

MainActivity.Java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
    private ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }
}
```

Activity_Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       ></Button>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```